# Change default color of * in PrimeFaces validation

Tags: jsf, primefaces

When I use the **"required="true""** for *form* validation in *PrimeFaces*, it gives star mark automatically in black color. I want change it to another color. There is no way to write *css* because *star* is not appeared by *PrimeFaces*.

How do I change it's default color to another color(red) ? 
This is the code in there documentation. I used it.

```
 <p:outputLabel for="firstname" value="Firstname:" />
 <p:inputText id="firstname" value="#{userView.firstname}" required="true" label="Firstname">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the CSS from your theme.

Example:

```
.ui-outputlabel .ui-outputlabel-rfi {
    color: blue;
}
```

Comment: its working.! thank for your answer.